# A DOSBox to PDF printer for mac

Tags: macos, mac, ventura

I need to print some files from a DOSBox program on Mac How do I do it?

I tried using old version of Ghostscript and Using Wine to use DOS Printer but neither of them worked

Comment: What sort of files? Are they just text, or do they need to be interpreted by something in DOSBox?

Comment: It prints to text, postscript and dbf they do not have to be interpreted and is directly converted to pdf

Comment: So do you actually need DOSBox? Text and PostScript are easily handled in MacOS. OpenOffice will open DBF files.

Comment: Yes also i mainly need to print prn

Comment: .prn files are usually just PostScript. You can use pstopdf on the Command Line.

Comment: And what about .prt files

Comment: I have talked with my software manager he says the software outputs .prt files which are  interpreted to .pdfs